# Does SignalR work on Mobile

Tags: mobile, signalr

It might be a simple question but I am struggling to find the asnwer.  Can anyone tell me if SignalR is supported across mobile browsers such as S3 or pads etc?  I can see it falls back to long polling if websockets are not supported but I can find out if this is supported in mobile browsers?  I found an online tic tac toe demo but this doesnt work on my mobile.

Thanks for anyhelp...

M

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in the browser or if native apps can do it?

If the browser supports the required transport specs, with long polling being the lowest common denominator, then it should work. It's "just" HTTP in the end. I can confirm it works in Android with Chrome for sure.

Same pretty much goes for native apps. If they have HTTP support, they should be able to use SignalR. There are a few implementations of SignalR clients for diff. mobile platforms out there already.