# SignalR and Mobile Devices

Tags: mobile, signalr

Does SignalR work on mobile devices ?

I've only found this [Does SignalR work on Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924292/does-signalr-work-on-mobile)
However there's no real answer there - one of the replys refers to web-socket support however SignalR is supposed to revert to long polling if web-sockets aren't supported.

Has any one used this in a real cross platform application ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have built an application which runs on:

**Win 7**

- Google Chrome
- FireFox
- Safari
- IE6/7/8/9/10

**Win 8**

- Google Chrome
- FireFox
- Safari
- IE10

**OSX**

- FireFox
- Google Chrome
- Safari

**iOS5 (IPhone 4, IPad 2)**

- Safari

**iOS6 (IPhone 4/5, IPad 2, new IPad)**

- Safari

**Android Froyo - Android current**

- default browser

**Windows Phone 7**

- default browser

SignalR works on all very well and will use the best transport for that device/OS/browser. The only problems I have seen are when using Opera browser.

If you have any issues with building a cross platform/browser app let me know as I have seen all sorts of crazy bugs!

Comment: Have you run into concurrent domain request issues? On iPad and iPhone you can't make requests after signalr is loaded because ios limits concurrent domain requests to 1. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1406

Comment: Yes. You just need to load any other resources from a different URL. I have created sub domains which point to the same site e.g. media.domain or images.domain

Comment: The answer says that it can be used on iOS and android, but on browsers. Can we integrate this library in our custom iOS or android application ?

Comment: My only issue with signalR has been iOS & Safari not loading completely, thereby preventing the rest of the page from loading (only when hosted on Windows 2012 R2 server). Works on IIS Express. Must be a bug or bad setting in IIS

Comment: You are best loading JavaScript/Images from a different URL from your SignalR hub. e.g. http://scripts.mydomain.com http://images.mydomain.com this way your browser will load these resources at the same time and not get locked up

Answer (score 1):

While the support on the browsers is good, the support for the mobile platforms is not up to date.  Microsoft is not focusing in keeping the android client api up to date (anti Android and iOS?).  The documentation is very poor as well.  With the help of a couple of non Microsoft resources, I could get it done with some effort.